# How to calculate statistics of not equally distributed "buckets"

Tags: probability, statistics

Firstly, if this has been asked elsewhere, I don't know how to search for it, so I apologize.

I have `n` directories. Given a file, I want to know what the likely-hood of guessing which directory this file should go in.

So, if I had 4, random chance would say it would be a 25% chance given that all files are equally distributed (not trying to account for remaining files... replacement?). But what if I knew that the distribution was `A - 50%, B - 25%, C - 20%, D - 5%`?

Given a random file (as the first file) how do I figure out what chance I have of guessing it correctly?

A bit about the background. I am creating a Deep Learning model that will attempt to group files together based on commonalities within the directories. I am achieving high 80% to low 90% accuracy with low loss... I guess I'm just wondering how accurate random would be if it knew the distribution of files.

Is this a "weighted probability" type problem?

Comment: Is there any other information available? If not, why should the base rate change?

Comment: I suppose if the "guesser" didn't know the distribution, the chance is the same. Or are you saying that the probability is still 25% regardless of the distribution?

Comment: When this test is given to pigeons, they have a far better strategy then humans.  Always guess the bin that gets more than the rest.  The problem as presented, you have a 50% chance to be right if you always guess A.  With no additional information there is no reason not to guess A.

Comment: That makes sense. A few comments have said, "with no other information." What type of information could be available that would change this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at **Baye's theorem** you notice, that the probabilities are not equal to the base rate (=*prior probability distribution*) only if you have new information available. However, if you have to place a single item and you do not have any information except that you know that there are $n$ directories, then you have to pick the directory according to the base rate distribution.

For your example you know that the failure rates are 
\begin{align}
P(\textrm{failure}|\textrm{chosen A}) &= 50\% \\ P(\textrm{failure}|\textrm{chosen B}) &= 75\% \\ P(\textrm{failure}|\textrm{chosen C}) &= 80\% \\ P(\textrm{failure}|\textrm{chosen D}) &= 95\% 
\end{align}
Now, one can think of situations, where it would make sense to choose to put a file into a directory other than $A$. E.g. if you expect unequal rewards. Hence, in general your choice depends on the so called *loss function*. However, if we assume that our goal is to obtain as few wrong sorted files as possible, we would put **all** files into directory $A$.